# How to display, populate details of non array in html ANGULAR

Tags: angular

I need to display the value of this function
so I have multiple data entirs in this table, and when the pencil glyph icon is clicked, it opens an open modal, where in i want to populate data of the selected edit option, like id and name of selected name should appear, how do i patch the values

```
   <table class="table table-scroll table-striped ">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th class="col-md-2" scope="col">ID</th>
                       <th class="col-md-2" scope="col">name(%)</th>
                      <th class="col-md-3" scope="col">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr
                      *ngFor="let data of showData"
                      id="{{ data.id }}"
                    >

                      <td>{{ data.id}}</td>
                      <td>{{ dada.name }}</td>
                      <td>
                        <span
                          class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"
                          (click)="request(data, template)"
                        ></span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

TS

```
  request(data, template) {

    this.popupDetails = data;
    this.openModal(template);
  }
```

so in the console, data is giving me all this data

```
   name: "Riya Sharma"
    id: 18
```

OPEN MODAL TEMPLATE---
i need to display it in my placeholder in my template 
like for id

```
<table class="table table-scroll table-striped ">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th class="col-md-2" scope="col">ID</th>
                           <th class="col-md-2" scope="col">name(%)</th>

                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr

                        >

                          <td><input
                    type="number"
                    min="0"
                    formControlName="id"
                    class="form-control input-sm "
                    placeholder="{{ data.id }}"
                  /></td>
                          <td><input
                    type="number"
                    min="0"
                    formControlName="id"
                    class="form-control input-sm "
                    placeholder="{{ data.id }}"
                  /></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
```

how do i do that cuz using ngfor gives me error saying, can't read non iterables
do i need to use patch method for it?

Comment: can you create https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it you need to display a property from the object `{ "name": "Riya Sharma", "id": 18 }`. And it looks like you've assigned the object response to the variable `popupDetails`. You can use it in the template to use the values.

Controller

```
popupDetails: any;   // <-- define value here

request(data, template) {
  console.log(data);   // <-- log the `data` here
  this.popupDetails = data;
  this.openModal(template);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
<input
  type="number"
  min="0"
  formControlName="id"
  class="form-control input-sm "
  placeholder="{{ popupDetails.id }}"
/>
```

I'd also tell you go through atleast Angular Tour of Heroes walkthrough [here](https://angular.io/tutorial) to get an idea of how Angular is structured.

Comment: this did not woek, it gave me blank inout, i have updated my question with more details

Comment: Please log the `data` parameter in the `request()` function and post the output. I've updated the code.

Comment: sorry, I re checked and ur previous solution worked, thank you so much!!

Comment: BTW, both variations `[placeholder]="popupDetails.id"` and `placeholder="{{ popupDetails.id }}"` will work. The former is called property binding and the latter is called interpolation. Learn more about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax).

Comment: how would i have to do it if i want the value to be displayed in the inout field instead of the placeholder?

Comment: Bind to the `input` property instead of `placeholder`. Remove `placeholder="{{ popupDetails.id }}"` and add `[input]="popupDetails.id"` or `input="{{popupDetails.id}}"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[placeholder]="{{popupDetails.id}}"` within your input tag.

Comment: not working, the placeholder just says, "popupDetails.id" as text

Comment: @rakshandaBhure, Try using `{{ }}`

Comment: how would i have to do it if i want the value to be displayed in the input field and not the  placeholder?

Comment: Bind it via `[(ngModel)]="popupDetails.id"`